# Chromium is not open Zoom by xdg-open

Tags: chromium, xdg-open, zoom-meeting

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Chromium 81.0.4044.138 and Zoom 5.0.403652.0509. When try to open link to Zoom conference appears window "Open xdg-open?". Unfortunately nothing happened.
I used tip from [this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219614/xdg-open-doesnt-do-anything-zoom-in-chromium) but unsuccessful.
Directly Zoom works. Chromium is default browser.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the new "snap" architecture.  It breaks not only links to zoom, but other things as well (linke magnet links)
The bug is documented here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1776873

Hopefully there can be a fix soon, this is a pain (it used to work in earlier versions!

Comment: 2020.06.22 - still not fixed. Indeed, a pain.  Thanks for your reply anyway - your time is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't know what happens, but now works.
*Chromium:* Version 83.0.4103.106 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)
*Zoom:* 5.0.403652.0509
Looks like fixed in Chromium.