# Browser won't open Zoom using xdg

Tags: chromium, zoom-meeting, xdg-open, xdg

I have installed Zoom on Ubuntu 22.04, but cannot login, since my browsers (any of them, firefox, chrome, brave) will not open Zoom by xdg tag zoommtg.

Some people had issues with the capital Z, but this is not my case ([Xdg-open doesn't do anything, Zoom in Chromium,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219614/xdg-open-doesnt-do-anything-zoom-in-chromium))
Here are my settings:

```
$ xdg-settings get default-url-scheme-handler zoommtg
zoom-client_zoom-client.desktop
```

.desktop is stored at

```
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/zoom-client_zoom-client.desktop
```

and executable is at

```
/snap/bin/zoom-client
```

Please advise. It's really an issue, since I cannot login using my institution, which means that I cannot login to Zoom using my account.

Edit: xdg works for other apps, so I guess it's a Zoom problem.

Comment: Primarily I'm using brave browser, which is also snap. Can I install non-snap brave?
But same thing with chrome, which i don't think is snap.

Comment: No, could be. Also chromium is snap if installed from the Ubuntu software app. All browsers are snap? But why it wouldn't work if they are snap?

Comment: Nope. I've reinstalled FF as a deb package, still the same issue. FF offers to open the zoom link by xdg in Zoom, everything looks fine, but then nothing happens. There must be another issue. 
Could the problem be that Zoom is snap? This would make less sense, thoughj

Comment: I am glad that you found the solution to your question and provided an answer. Please accept your answer as the correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✓ and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

Comment: Did anyone find any solution for that? I'm with the exact same issue.

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1289641 this worked for me. I think I finally had to install the .deb version but it still wasn't quite working, then finally this worked.

Answer (score 1):

I removed zoom-client from snap, sudo snap remove zoom-client, then installed an un-sandboxed version of zoom using a .deb file following info from this site: https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-zoom-client-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-linux/

That worked for me, now I can launch zoom with a zoom link from my company.